# Ancora è una locuzione aggettivale?

Tags: grammar

Molto spesso viene sostituito senza troppe distinzioni all'aggettivo indefinito *altro* o *ulteriore*:

1. "Voglio ancora/altro/ulteriore pollo"
2. "Serve ancora/altro/ulteriore denaro"
3. "Mi serve altra/ulteriore/ancora fiducia"
4. "Due ulteriori/Altri due/ancora due passi e si arriva".

[Qui viene dato sinonimo di "in più"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/ancora_2) ma sinceramente non mi suona molto

Comment: No, non è una locuzione e non è aggettivale. Se nessuno lo fa prima, quando ho tempo scrivo una risposta.

Comment: Si dice "ulteriore pollo"?

Comment: @Charo: Dico "altro denaro" o "ulteriore denaro". Allo stesso tempo dico "altro pollo/pasta/carne ecc... "  e quindi anche l'aggettivo "ulteriore" dovrebbe essere corretto grammaticalmente, nonostante suoni artificioso.

Comment: Vorrei osservare che "ancora" è un avverbio, e, sebbene le diverse versioni delle quattro frasi siano abbastanza simili nel significato, gli aggettivi altro e ulteriore si riferiscono sempre al nome, mentre ancora si riferisce al verbo nelle prime tre frasi e all'aggettivo "due" nella quarta. Ancora somiglia più ad altri avverbi come nuovamente o ulteriormente, daccapo, o a locuzioni avverbiali come un'altra volta, di nuovo.

Comment: Non c'entra tantissimo. Molti amici bergamaschi usano "ancora" in vece di  "già", "Hai ancora visto il Gius?", "Hai già visto Giuseppe?"

Answer (score 7):

Intanto, quando si parla di “locuzioni aggettivali” (o avverbiali etc.) ci si riferisce specificamente a sequenze di due o più parole che svolgano complessivamente la funzione di un aggettivo (o avverbio etc.). Vedi per esempio la [voce “Locuzione aggettivale”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/locuzioni-aggettivali_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) dell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani. Quindi questa sicuramente non può essere una locuzione.

“Ancora” è semplicemente un avverbio (e in certi casi una congiunzione). In quanto avverbio si può usare con un verbo, senza altri complementi (“Hai finito?” “No, mangio ancora”); o insieme ad altri complimenti (“Faccio ancora due giri”, “Ci provo ancora in un altro modo” e così via).

Il dizionario di Internazionale che citi fu curato da Tullio De Mauro, e quindi le risposte che ti dà sono sicuramente più affidabili di quello che posso dirti io (o, mi permetto di dire, probabilmente chiunque altro qui). Il senso di “ancora” a cui ti riferisci è quello indicato lì con 2b, cioè appunto “in aggiunta” (“vuole ancora denaro”, “voglio ancora zucchero”).

Nei tuoi esempi, e in questi del denaro e dello zucchero, effettivamente il  senso è molto simile a quello che si avrebbe usando “altro” o “ulteriore”, ma ciò non fa di “ancora” un aggettivo.

Comment: grazie mille per la risposta. Una curiosità: quando dici  che "ancora" in queste frasi è molto simile a "ulteriore" e "altro" ti riferisci a tutte e 4 le frasi che ho fatto o solo un paio in particolare?

Comment: @Nakamura: In teoria sì, anche se alcune delle combinazioni che enumeri mi suonano molto poco idiomatiche (in particolare alcune di quelle con “ulteriore” e tutte quelle sulla fiducia: direi qualcosa come “Dovrei avere più fiducia”).

Comment: capisco. Alcune forse non risultano così tanto idiomatiche, ma possiamo comunque dire che ogni frase da me scritta è corretta grammaticalmente e utilizzabile al 100%? Ciò che mi preme è la correttezza grammaticale. Scusa se rispondo in ritardo

Comment: Scusa l'insistenza, ma quali sono nello specifico le frasi che risultano poco idionatiche?

Comment: @Nakamura: A mio avviso, tutte quelle frasi sono grammaticali, ma alcune non verrebbero mai pronunciate spontaneamente da un italiano. È come “lavo le mie mani” al posto di “mi lavo le mani”: dal punto grammaticale non ha niente che non vada, ma suona come una cattiva traduzione. Come accennavo, la frase sulla fiducia la formulerei diversamente, e userei “ulteriore” solo in un registro piuttosto formale (“sono necessari ulteriori dati per poter procedere”).

Comment: Grazie mille per la risposta. In poche parole le frasi che non suonano, nonostante siano corrette sono: la 3 accompagnata dagli aggettivi "altro" e "ulteriore" e l'avverbio "ancora", poi la 1, la 2 e la 4 con l'aggettivo "ulteriore". Dico bene? Confermi che si tratta di queste frasi?

Comment: Scusa ma non riusciyo a menzionarti.